# How to change URL of opencart project using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, opencart

I have a issue of URL of `opencart` project.

I installed `oepncart` project but it's URL is:

```
http://www.exmaple.com/opencart/upload
```

But i want to display it like:

`http://www.exmple.com/demo`  using `.htaccess`

How can i change it?

Any one help please.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^demo$ /opencart/upload [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You'll need to modify the `RewriteBase` to be pointing to Your subdirectory from the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On                # Already in there

RewriteBase /opencart/upload/   # Already there but with value / only
```

and then of course use a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^demo$ /opencart/upload [QSA]   # Add this before the next line that is already there
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```